# Get action name of intent filter located in service tags in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-manifest, android-intentservice

I need to get action name of intent filter located in service tags from specified installed package name.
Actually, this issue may related to parsing AndroidManifest.xml file, but I want to use relevant functions/classes provided by Android to get action name instead of parsing xml directly.

Well, to put it more clearly;
I am writing a code that gets installed apps and then filters media apps.
When I compare manifest files of some media applications, I figured out that the common thing they use "**android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService**" action name. So, I thought I could create a filter by looking for this service action name.

Here is a sample snippet from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<service
    android:name="com.example.mediabrowser.XXXMediaBrowserService"
    android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
...
```

I hope everything has been well understood so far.
After realizing all this stuff, I pulled the services name from the installed package name by filtering Intent.ACTION_MAIN.

```
    final List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

    for(PackageInfo pi : packages)
    {
            pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pi.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
            Log.e("SERVICES: ", pi.packageName + Arrays.toString(pi.services));
    }
```

This code just presents me the service list. So I was able to capture the service name *"com.example.mediabrowser.XXXMediaBrowserService"* in the AndroidManifest.xml that I mentioned above.

My purpose is to pull the action name (android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService) that belongs to  in this service. I tried a few methods on how to do this, but I couldn't get any results.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news!

The solution is here,

```
final Intent providerIntent = new Intent(MediaBrowserService.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
    List<ResolveInfo> mediaApps = pm.queryIntentServices(providerIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : mediaApps) {
        Log.e("MEDIA APPS: ", String.valueOf((info.serviceInfo.packageName)));
    }
```

Best regards...